# PHP - Sanitise a comma separated string

Tags: php, csv, user-input, sanitization

What would be the most efficient way to clean a user input that is a comma separated string made entirely on numbers - e.g

> 2,40,23,11,55

I use this function on a lot of my inputs

```
function clean($input){ $input=mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($input,ENT_QUOTES)); return $input; }
```

And on simple integers I do:

```
if (!filter_var($_POST['var'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)) {echo('error - bla bla'); exit;}
```

So should I explode it and then check every element of the array with the code above or maybe replace all occurrences of ',' with '' and then check the whole thing is a number? What do you guys think?

Comment: Both answers work a treat, thanks. I tested them though and jitter's answer is about 4 times more efficient. +1 both of you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (ctype_digit(str_replace(",", "", $input))) {
  //all ok. very strict. input can only contain numbers and commas. not even spaces
} else {
  //not ok
}
```

If it is CSV and if there might be spaces around the digits or commas and maybe even some quotation marks better use a regex to check if it matches

Comment: You may want to remove white space as well - depends on the "csv" one is dealing with.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (!preg_match('/\A\d+(,\d+)*\z/', $input)) die('bad input');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to transform a comma-separated list instead of simply rejecting it if it's not formed correctly, you could do it with [`array_map()`](http://php.net/array_map) and avoid writing an explicit loop.

```
$sanitized_input = implode(",", array_map("intval", explode(",", $input)));
```

Comment: I was going to agree that personally, I don't bother error checking, I just filter, but then I noticed that your code inserts zeros when there are two commas side-by-side.

Answer (score 0):

I would filter instead of error checking on simple input, though only 'cause I'm lazy, I suppose, and usually in a web context there's way too many cases to handle on what could be coming in that I wouldn't expect:  Simple filter below.

```
<?php
$input = '234kljsalkdfj234a,a, asldkfja 345345sd,f jasld,f234l2342323@#$@#';
function clean($dirty){ // Essentially allows numbers and commas, just strips everything else.
    return preg_replace('/[^0-9,]/', "", (string) $dirty);
}

$clean = clean($input);

echo $clean;
// Result: 234234,,345345,,2342342323
// Note how it doesn't deal with adjacent filtered-to-empty commas, though you could handle those in the explode.  *shrugs*
```

?>

Here's the code and the output on codepad:

http://codepad.org/YfSenm9k